# Number of ways to arrange different poker chips. (Recursion)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

Assume there are poker chips in four different colors and one of the colors is blue. In how many ways can **n** amount of chips be piled on top of each other without two blue ones being next to one another?

Comment: Hint: You have n! ways to arrange the chips of the first three colors.

Comment: yeah, that I know. It's the blue one that's causing me headache.

Comment: If $b$ of the $n$ chips are blue, in how many ways can a blue chip be inserted into the stack of $n - b$ chips so that no two blue chips are next to each other?

Comment: Do you know how to solve recurrences of the type $a_{n+2}=pa_{n+1}+qa_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a pile of chips with no consecutive blues **good.^^ Let $b_n$ be the number of good piles of $n$ chips with a blue as the top chip. Let $c_n$ be the number of good piles of $n$ with blue not the top chip.

Note that
$$b_{n+1}=c_n.\tag{1}$$
This is because we get a good arrangement of $n+1$ chips with blue on top by putting a blue on top of a good arrangement of height $n$ with blue not on top. Also,
$$c_{n+1}=3(b_n+c_n),\tag{2}$$
since we get a good pile of $n+1$ with blue not on top by putting a chip of one of the $3$ non-blue colours on top of any good pile of $n$.

Bump the index of Recurrence (2) up by $1$. We get
$$c_{n+2}=3b_{n+1} +3c_{n+1}.$$
Using Recurrence (1), we get
$$c_{n+2}=3c_{n+1}+3c_n.\tag{3}$$

Solve Recurrence, (3) by some standard method. Or else if you are comfortable with matrix manipulation, solve the system of recurrences (1), (2).

Now that we have $c_n$, we know $b_n$. The number of good piles of $n$ chips is $b_n+c_n$.